Conditional distribution of a random vector given maximum
I have been working on a problem in multivariate analysis related to the conditional distributions of random vectors given their maxima when the margins are not necessarily independent. The joint distribution of the margins and their maximum is not absolutely continuous so we can't use densities. In particular, I am interested in the case where the distribution of the vector is given by an extreme-value copula, e.g, the gumbel copula.
I've not been able to find much about this problem outside of the independence case. What is known about these sort of conditional distributions? Are there any good references that I should take a look at to get started with this?
Thank you
